# How to get GNOME volume applet back?

Tags: debian, gnome2

I'm running GNOME 2.30 (Squeeze) and have lost my Volume Control applet. I can't find it in my **Add to Panel** window.

[image]

[**update**] Note that the Volume Control applet appears again in the window, and I have no idea what fixed the issue.

Comment: Do you still have your "user" toolbar next to the date?
Because I think it may be "Notification zone" item.

Answer (score 4):

**Add to Panel > Indicator Applet**

[image]

**OR**

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>  and run this:  `gnome-volume-control-applet`
- Also, add `gnome-volume-control-applet` to **System > Preferences > Startup Applications**

Answer (score 3):

It's called `mixer_applet2` and should be part of the [gnome-applets package](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/gnome-applets).  On Debian Squeeze, it should be installed as `/usr/lib/gnome-applets/mixer_applet2`.  I'm not using Debian, but it shows up as Volume Control in my Add to Panel dialog.

You might try reinstalling gnome-applets.

Comment: This conflicts with iamsid's Answer.

Comment: @Tshepang, I know, but the fact remains that I'm using Gnome 2.30, and gnome-applets 2.30.0 contains a mixer_applet2 that can be added as Volume Control.  I don't have any Indicator Applet in my Add to Panel dialog.  I don't know where his came from.

Comment: I meant conflict in a sense that she says `gnome-volume-control-applet` and you say `mixer_applet2`. BTW, I also use 2.30 and I have the `/usr/lib/gnome-applets/mixer_applet2` file.

Comment: @Tshepang, I don't have a `gnome-volume-control-applet` on my system, just `mixer_applet2`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is now under 'Indicator applet' or something like that.  Lost my too, but got it back.

Comment: Just checked from home--yes, it's called 'Indicator applet'.  Whoever voted this down may rethink his decision.

Comment: Is that maybe Gnome 2.32?  I'm using 2.30, and I have a Volume Control applet (mixer_applet2) but no Indicator Applet.

Comment: @cjm: whoops, yes it's 2.32 already.  Time flies like bullet, you know :)